# I want to install vim but the following error appears

Tags: command-line

```
checking for tgetent()... configure: error: NOT FOUND!
      You need to install a terminal library; for example ncurses.
      Or specify the name of the library with --with-tlib.
```

Comment: If you want to install Vim, why not `sudo apt-get install vim`?

Comment: How are you installing it? What command did you run tat gave those errors? If you're installing from source: i) *Why?* See muru's comment above; ii) where did you get the source tarball from? Please [edit] your question and clarify what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

Open a Terminal and execute this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
```